# Partial view submitting multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I'm trying to submit a comments to a "blog", using partial view, because
there a few blog I'm adding the partial view in a foreach loop, so when I post a comment to any blog is is posting N time (n=number of blogs in the view), how can I prevent multiTimes Submit?

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    //clearCode
    foreach (var Coment in item.Comments)
    {
        //clearCode
    }

    using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubjectReview", "Reviews",

    new AjaxOptions()
    {
        Url = Url.Action("SubjectReview", "Reviews")
    }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="hidden" value=@item.ReviewId name="hidden">
        {
            Html.RenderAction("_CommetsSubmit", "Reviews");
        }
    }
}
```